# Excel VBA - Storing table column into a range variable

Tags: vba, excel, range, listobject

I am currently experimenting with excel VBAs `ListObjects` which is the object type of an excel table. I would like to **store a table column range into a variable**.

Here is what I can do:

```
'store a group of cells into a range variable
dim rng as Range
set rng = activesheet.Range("A1:A10")

'select a table column
dim table as ListObject
set table = activesheet.listobjects("Table1")
table.ListColumns(1).Range.Select
```

While both of the above work, I don't understand why the following does't work: (**EDIT: it works**)

```
dim rng_column as Range
set rng_column = table.ListColumns(1).Range
```

I experimented with other variable types, such as `variant` or `ListColumn`, however, nothing stored the cells into the variable. In the example above, there is no error, but the variable `rng_column` remains `<empty>`
I know there are other workarounds, but I really want to understand what's the issue here.

---

**UPDATE**
After some helpful comments I could narrow the problem down. Everything worked normally. However, I made two mistakes.

First, I had a spelling error in the variable names. (I should have included option explicit to notice this earlier).

Second, I passed the range variable on to another range variable, where I forgot to include the `set` keyword when doing so..

Hopefully someone can learn from my mistakes..

Comment: That code works for me. Is the table definitely where you think it is? `rng` does not appear to be relevant here?

Comment: They work for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: Try this line at the end and see what it returns `MsgBox rng_column(1)`.

Comment: I don't get an error, I try to stick the `rng_column` variable into the following `WorksheetFunction.Match(search, rng_column, 0)`. Here comes an error, because `rng_column` is empty. In debug mode it shows <empty> above the variable

Comment: Thanks @SJR, it works. I guess the error must lie somewhere else..

Answer (score 1):

you have a misnomer in the title. technically you cannot store any data into a range variable.

a range variable is a reference (a pointer) to a cell, or a group of cells. the data gets stored in the cells that the range variable points to.

if you need to store data from a range, then assign the range.value to an array

if you want to store data from a single cell then assign the value to a "regular" (non object) variable (string, integer, long ... )